# How to handle blank in formatted integer input

Tags: fortran, fortran90, formatted-input

I have a file like this

```
1980  01  23 

1982  04  30
1983  05  22
1984        
1985  02  11
```

I tried to read data using format "(3I4)"

```
implicit none

integer, parameter :: FUnitIn = 10
character(len=255) :: FNameIn = "./test.txt"


integer :: FStatOpen, FStatRead
integer :: yyyy, mm, dd


open ( unit    = FUnitIn, &
       file    = trim(FNameIn), &
       access  = "sequential", &
       form    = "formatted", &
       status  = "old", &
       iostat  = FStatOpen)
if (FStatOpen /= 0) then ! ERROR
    stop
end if


do
    read (FUnitIn, "(3I4)", iostat=FStatRead) yyyy, mm, dd
    if (FStatRead /= 0) then
        exit
    else
        write (6, "(3I4)") yyyy, mm, dd
    end if
end do
```

I got three zeros for the blank line.
Are there any options to handle blank input?

Comment: Welcome please supply the details. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What would you like to happen when there are blanks entries in the reading?

Comment: I mean the obvious answer would be to check for the zeros. After all, there is no year, month, or day 0. Alternatively you could read it into a temporary string, then you can analyse the string to see whether it is valid, and only then read from the string into values.

Answer (score 0):

You can read each line in a character variable, and check its adjusted-trimmed length if your sole goal is to skip the empty line, something like the following code (see variable `record`). Going beyond this simple implementation requires some extra information from you as to what behavior exactly you want to get.

```
implicit none

integer, parameter  :: FUnitIn = 10
character(len=255)  :: FNameIn = "./test.txt"


integer             :: FStatOpen, FStatRead
integer             :: yyyy, mm, dd
character(len=1023) :: record


open ( unit    = FUnitIn, &
    file    = trim(FNameIn), &
    access  = "sequential", &
    form    = "formatted", &
    status  = "old", &
    iostat  = FStatOpen)
if (FStatOpen /= 0) then ! ERROR
    stop
end if


do
    read (FUnitIn, "(3I4)", iostat=FStatRead) record
    if (FStatRead /= 0) then
        exit
    elseif ( len_trim(adjustl(record)) > 0 ) then
        read (record, *) yyyy, mm, dd            
        write (6, "(3I4)") yyyy, mm, dd
    end if
end do
```